# How to merge multiple datetime columns into one column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with three different datetime columns I'd like to merge into one column. Although the rows don't overlap for the most part, one datetime column sometimes overlaps with the first, but when it does overlap it's always the same date, so when I merge those two columns I'd just want to display one date for that.

Here's what my dataframe looks like:

```
Form Date     Form Date.2   Form Date.3
2021-01-05                  
2021-02-05                  
                            2021-03-02
              2021-03-22    
2021-01-06    2021-01-06
                            2021-02-12
2021-01-09
              2021-02-19
2021-01-09    2021-01-09
```

What I'd like to create is this:

```
Form Date     Form Date.2   Form Date.3   Merged Form Dates
2021-01-05                                2021-01-05 
2021-02-05                                2021-02-05   
                            2021-03-02    2021-03-02
              2021-03-22                  2021-03-22
2021-01-06    2021-01-06                  2021-01-06
                            2021-02-12    2021-02-12
2021-01-09                                2021-01-09
              2021-02-19                  2021-02-19
2021-01-09    2021-01-09                  2021-01-09
```

I've tried `df['Merged Form Dates'] = df['Form Date'] + df['Form Date.1']+ df['Form Date.2']` but it says I can't add datetimearray and datetimearray. I also tried `df['Merged Form Dates'] = df.merge(df['Form Date]' + df['Form Date.1'] + df['Form Date.2'])` but it says I can only concatenate list (not "DatetimeArray") to list.

I greatly appreciate the help with this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly select your required columns:

```
column=['Form Date','Form Date.1','Form Date.2']
```

After that make use of `apply()` method and `strip()` method:

```
df['Merged Form Dates']=df[column].astype(str).apply(set,1).apply(''.join).str.strip('nan')
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting closer to my answer. However, I simplified my data frame above, I have many other columns with different data types in my dataframe that are merging when I apply your suggested solution. How do I specify that the only columns I want to merge are the form date columns?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, it's outputting some weird numbers when I specified one column. It also doesn't seem to work for multiple columns too, gives me an error.

Comment: what error you are getting and what weird numbers you are getting.?.pls tell

Comment: If i specify one column, df['Form Date'], it outputs 1302-, 1042-, 012-, etc. If I specify more than one column says KeyError: ('Form Date', 'Form Date.2')

Comment: what is the output of `df.columns`? I think its due to the presence of `' '` in column name

Comment: That gives me AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'apply'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231582/discussion-between-slickspidey-and-anurag-dabas).